# Customise error message on asp.net range validator

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi is it possible to change the error message of a asp.net range validator based on the value of the textbox. For example if the number is below 0, display the error message, "number can not be less than 0" and if it is above the max value set the error message to "number can't be above maxvalue".

```
if (stockCount < Convert.ToInt32(range.MinimumValue))
{
    range.ErrorMessage = "Quantity has to be minumm of 1";
}
else if (stockCount > Convert.ToInt32(range.MaximumValue))
{
    range.ErrorMessage = "Not enough items in stock";
}
```

this is the code which i have had no success with, any suggestions or advice is more than appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe my answer didn't show two different messages, but i think it simpler and cleaner to summarized the message in one error message.
you can use Class and put Range validator with error message on top.

I am very sorry if my suggestion is not to your liking.

```
public class Example
{
    [Range(10, 1000, ErrorMessage = "Value must be between {1} and {2}.")]
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple jQuery listener on the TextBox and change the error message based on it's input.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>').keyup(function () {
        var validator = document.getElementById('<%= RangeValidator1.ClientID %>');
        var errorMsg = 'Your value of ' + $(this).val() + ' is incorrect (max is ' + validator.maximumvalue + ')';
        $('#<%= RangeValidator1.ClientID %>').text(errorMsg);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want in ASP.NET and C# only try below way of doing:

Declare a `rangevalidator` for your text box

```
 <asp:TextBox id="text1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
 <asp:RangeValidator EnableClientScript="false" 
                          id="RangeValidator1" 
                          runat="server" 
                          ControlToValidate="text1" >
      </asp:RangeValidator>
```

You have to invoke `Validate()` function of `RangeValidator`.
And in your code, try below pseudo code where ever you want to validate. (Not tested)

```
    RangeValidator1.MinimumValue = 0;
    RangeValidator1.MaximumValue = 10;
    RangeValidator1.Type = ValidationDataType.Integer;
    RangeValidator1.Validate();

    if (!RangeValidator1.IsValid)
    {
         if(Convert.ToInt32(text1.Text) < 0)
         {
            RangeValidator1.ErrorMessage = "number can not be less than 0";    
         }
         else
         {
             RangeValidator1.ErrorMessage = "number can't be above maxvalue";    
         }    
    }
```

Comment: trying your advice now!, looks promising

Comment: Thanks.  also look into this link.... but more explanation. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxet6xwx.aspx